# Determine if a substring is numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL server 2008 i have data in column 'Column' as below :

> Column
>
> stringA (12345)
>
> stringB (83859)
>
> stringC (47326)
>
> StringD (Unwanted)

I'm returning the information in the brackets using the following SQL:

```
select rm.column
    , charindex('(', rm.column)
    , charindex(')', rm.column)
    , SUBSTRING(rm.column, charindex('(', rm.column) + 1, charindex(')', rm.column) - charindex('(', rm.column))-1 
from tableRemove rm
where remover = charindex('(', rm.column) > 0
```

I would like only data where the information contained in the brackets is numeric ie 12345, 83859, 47326 and not 'unwanted'.

I can't use 'ISNUMERIC' as it will return always false (substring is used to grab the information in brackets).

I can't use 'CAST' as this will return an error on string datatypes.

Is there a way to determine if a string type is numeric/ can be converted to numeric?

Comment: Which version of `SQL SERVER` you are using

Comment: @Prdp 2008, says in line 1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the below script.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        col VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'stringA (12345)' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'stringB (83859)' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'stringC (47326)' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'StringD (Unwanted)' 


;with cte_1
AS
(select rm.col
    , SUBSTRING(rm.col, charindex('(', rm.col) + 1, charindex(')', rm.col)-1 - charindex('(', rm.col) )FilterdData
from @Table rm)

SELECT *
FROM cte_1
WHERE ISNUMERIC(IntValue)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `LIKE`

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT columnname, 
                Substring(rm.columnname, Charindex('(', rm.columnname) + 1,Charindex(')', rm.columnname) - Charindex('(', rm.columnname)- 1) AS extract_data 
         FROM   (SELECT 'stringA (12345)' 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 'stringB (83859)' 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 'stringC (47326)' 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 'StringD (Unwanted)') rm (columnname)) 
SELECT columnname, 
       extract_data 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  extract_data NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

For `SQL SERVER 2012+` we can use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT`

```
SELECT columnname, 
       extract_data 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  TRY_CONVERT(bigint,extract_data) is not null
```

or

```
WHERE  TRY_CAST(extract_data  as bigint) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use both:

```
Select isnumeric(SUBSTRING(rm.column, 
              charindex('(', rm.column) + 1, 
               len(rm.column) - charindex('(', rm.column))-1)
```

EDIT:

I just ran this and I get no errors:

```
Declare @s varchar(200) = 'stringA (12345)'
Select isnumeric(subString(@s, 
              charindex('(', @s) + 1, 
              len(@s) - 1 - charindex('(', @s)))
```

Comment: This was my first thought aswell Charles, unfortunately I get a type converstion error with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select rm.column
, charindex('(', rm.column)
, charindex(')', rm.column)
, SUBSTRING(rm.column, charindex('(', rm.column) + 1, charindex(')', rm.column) - charindex('(', rm.column))-1 from tableRemove rm  where remover = charindex('(', rm.column) > 0  AND rm.column not like '%[^0-9]%'
```